# Using all ports of MSP430 as one big port - is it possible?

Tags: embedded, msp430, memory-mapping

It will be more convenient for me to use all the MSP430 ports as one port.
I was thinking maybe to overflow the registers until the next memory address, but it's not working (or maybe i'm not doing it right).

To access **BIT0** of **PORT2**, I tried Something like that:

```
P1OUT |= 0x80000000000;
```

because in the memory **P2OUT** (0x0029)  is 8 addresses after **P1OUT** (0x0021), 
and those are 8bit registers in the middle. so 8x8=64.

I know I can access the **P2OUT** with an offset like this:

```
*(char *)(0x0021 + 0x0008)  |=  BIT0;
```

I want to define myself a list of GPIO's from 1 to 13, and turn them on and off without checking if GPIO11 is on **PORT2** or on **PORT1**, I want one command to do it all.

is is possible?

Comment: Do mean something like `GPIO11 = 1;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
P1OUT |= 0x80000000000;
```

This does not work because

1. you did not count bits correctly:

   ```c
   P1OUT |= 0x10000000000000000;
   ```
2. `P1OUT` is an 8-bit register, so the compiler would throw away all but the lowest eight bits. You would have to use a data type that is large enough (and the bit you want to set is the 65th bit in memory, so you'd need a type larger than 64 bits):

   ```c
   *(uint128_t*)&P1OUT |= 0x10000000000000000;
   ```
3. There is no 128-bit type.

---

You can get what you want with another layer of indirection:

```c
volatile uint8_t * const ports[] = { &P1OUT, &P2OUT, &P3OUT };

static inline void setGPIO(unsigned int number)
{
    *ports[number / 8] |= 1 << (number % 8);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I like your solution!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `1 << (number % 8)` or equivalently `1 << (number & 7)`?  The argument to the OR operator is a bitmask, not a bit index.

Comment: @BenVoigt: note that this will add significant overhead to your code. Also, some MSP430 already allow to access two adjacent ports (P1/2, P3/4) by a single 16 bit read/write. Normally for embedded systems, you would use `one #define' for port and bit-number/mask instead which are named for their symbolic usage. Put that into some `hardware_config.h` you include in each affected source file and you'r fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt, CL: This should better be either `uint16_t`/etc. or - best `size_t`.

Comment: @Olaf The CPU used here, the G2553, does not have 16-bit ports. And where would `size_t` make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the x5xx-family with PA/PB/... Which one does the TO use actually; did I miss that in his question?. See the rationale for size_t in the standard. Your approach would require a similar table for all other registers like `PxIN`, `PxDIR`, `PxSEL`, ...Each table costs Flash and needs at least some wrapper function. Otherwise the whole approach is just inconsistent. Not to mention the added code for the caalculations which costs clock cycles (interrupt-handler, Power!).

Answer (score 1):

No, surplus data does not overflow from one memory address to the next. If you write data to an 8-bit address, the extra (most significant) bits are truncated.

There are several ways you can approach this. You can have a set of functions for each port bit, for example

```
write_GPIO_11(int bitval) {             // pass 0 or 1
    if (bitval)
        P2OUT |= 0x08;
    else
        P2OUT &= 0xF7;
}
```

Or have separate functions `set_GPIO_11` and `clear_GPIO_11`, which would be more efficient and better for `inline` functions.

You could also use macros

```
#define GP11_ON (P2OUT |= 0x08)

...

GP11_ON;
```

However since you talk about overflowing from one port to the next, I wonder if you also want to write all 13 bits with a single instruction (which would have to be 16-bit value). This can't be done with a single write, but you could have a single function call, which again could be `inline`.

```
write_GPIO_bits(unsigned int bitvals) {
    P1OUT = bitvals;
    P2OUT = bitvals >> 8;
}
```

And so on.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't want to write so many function since I have a memory limit, so I wanted to make it shorter as it can be.
@CL. 's answer might fit me needs

Comment: Then perhaps the macro approach will suit you, since inline code executes quicker. But using functions does not necessarily use more code memory.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach:

"hardware_config.h":

```
#define CONCAT_(a, b) a##b

#define BITSET(p, m) (CONCAT(p, OUT) |= m)

#define LEDGN_PORT P1
#define LEDGN_MASK 0x01
```

The helper functions might better reside in a different header file.

Usage:

```
BITSET(LEDGN_PORT, LEDGN_MASK);
```

This adds no overhead to program code.